# wkhtmltopdf div size issue(div made by javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, css, wkhtmltopdf

everyone.
Please teach me how to fix this if you can.

I want to make pdf file of web site which I made with wkhtmltopdf.
But it makes diffrence in division height between browser and pdf file.

for example
[when browser](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTUKC.png)

when viewed in the browser like this.two divs are same height.

[when pdf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJpic.png)

but the pdf made from same page is like this.two divs are not same height.

and the javascript setHeight code is here

```
function heigtSet() {
$('#printoutput>div').each(function(){
    console.log('test');
    console.log($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height());
    console.log($(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height());
    if ($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height()>$(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height()){
        $(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height()-15);
    }else{
        $(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height($(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height()+15);
    }
});
```

}

please help me.

※add information

html(php), css and javascript are here

and command of wkhtmltopdf is this

wkhtmltopdf --javascript-delay 2000 --zoom 0.8 --viewport-size 1024x760 --orientation landscape --load-error-handling ignore sampleurl sample.pdf'

```js
function dataSet(pType) {
 var resultAvg = new Object;
 var t_total_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total_mid_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total_mid_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total_mid_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total_mid_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total_non_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total_non_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total_non_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total_non_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total_num = 0;

 var t_total2_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total2_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total2_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total2_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total2_mid_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total2_mid_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total2_mid_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total2_mid_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total2_non_adaptation_1 = 0;
 var t_total2_non_adaptation_2 = 0;
 var t_total2_non_adaptation_3 = 0;
 var t_total2_non_adaptation_4 = 0;
 var t_total2_num = 0;

 var t_total_1_num = 0;
 var t_total_mid_num = 0;
 var t_total_nonmid_num = 0;
 var t_total_sub_1_num = 0;
 var t_total_sub_mid_num = 0;
 var t_total_sub_nonmid_num = 0;
 var t_group_name_list = new Array;
 var t_group_name = '';

 console.log('testworld');
 for(key in result){
  if(key!='group_name'){
   var group = result[key];

   resultAvg[group['name']] = new Object;
   t_group_name_list.push(group['name']);
   var t_sub_num = 0;

   group['member'].forEach(function(member){

    if (resultAvg[group['name']][member['subgroup']]==undefined){
     resultAvg[group['name']][member['subgroup']] = new Object;
     resultAvg[group['name']][member['subgroup']]['member'] = new Array;
    }
    resultAvg[group['name']][member['subgroup']]['member'].push(member);
    t_total_num++;
    t_sub_num++;

    if (member['1_flag']=='1'){
     t_total_1_num++;
     t_total_adaptation_3 += member['adaptation_3']['standard_score'];
     t_total_adaptation_4 += member['adaptation_4']['standard_score'];
    }else{
     if (member['mid_joined_flag']=='1'){
      t_total_mid_num++;
      t_total_mid_adaptation_1 += member['adaptation_1']['standard_score'];
      t_total_mid_adaptation_2 += member['adaptation_2']['standard_score'];
      t_total_mid_adaptation_3 += member['adaptation_3']['standard_score'];
      t_total_mid_adaptation_4 += member['adaptation_4']['standard_score'];
     }else{
      t_total_nonmid_num++;
      t_total_non_adaptation_1 += member['adaptation_1']['standard_score'];
      t_total_non_adaptation_2 += member['adaptation_2']['standard_score'];
      t_total_non_adaptation_3 += member['adaptation_3']['standard_score'];
      t_total_non_adaptation_4 += member['adaptation_4']['standard_score'];
     }
     t_total_adaptation_1 += member['adaptation_1']['standard_score'];
     t_total_adaptation_2 += member['adaptation_2']['standard_score'];
     t_total_adaptation_3 += member['adaptation_3']['standard_score'];
     t_total_adaptation_4 += member['adaptation_4']['standard_score'];
    }
   });

  }else{
   t_group_name = result[key];
  }

 }


 var thtml = '';
 var tnum = 1;

 thtml += '<div id="contents" class="contentsPage'+tnum+'"><div id="headerCont"><div id="titles"><h1><span>適応感レポート</span>で可視化する組織の適応状況</h1><div class="names"><p class="subtitles">'+pType+'</p><p class="group">';
 thtml += t_group_name;
 thtml += '</p></div></div></div>';
 thtml += '<div id="leftCont"><section id="adaptation"><h2>adp1</h2><div class="adaptationCnt"><div id="grph1" class="grphXY"><div class="grphY"><div class="grphY1 grphUnit">high</div><div class="grphY2 grphUnit">low</div><div class="grphYtitle grphTitle">adp</div><div class="grphYSub grphSub">adp</div></div><div class="grphPlot"><table><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><td></td><td></td><td></td></tr></table><ul class="grphPoint"><li></li><li style="top:107px"></li></ul></div><div class="grphX"><div class="grphX1 grphUnit">high<span>▲</span></div><div class="grphX2 grphUnit"><span>▼</span>low</div><div class="grphXtitle grphTitle">force</div><div class="grphXSub grphSub">desc</div></div>';

 thtml += '</div><div class="clearfix"></div></div></section></div>';
 thtml += '<div id="rightCont"><section id="adaptationDetail"><h2>adp2</h2><div class="adaptationCnt"><table><tbody class="thead"><tr><th class="dataTitleText"><p>low</p></th><th></th><th class="dataTitleText"><p>mid</p></th><th class="dataTitleText"><p>hight</p></th></tr></tbody><tbody><tr><th class="tate">adp1</th><td><p class="meterBar"></p><p class="av1"></p><p class="av2"></p></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><th class="tate">adp2</th><td><p class="meterBar"></p><p class="av1"></p><p class="av2"></p></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><th class="tate">adp3</th><td><p class="meterBar"></p><p class="av1"></p><p class="av2"></p></td><td></td><td></td></tr><tr><th class="tate">adp4</th><td><p class="meterBar"></p><p class="av1"></p><p class="av2"></p></td><td></td><td></td></tr></tbody></table><div class="adaptationDetailText adaptationDetailText1"><p class="av1"></p>av1</div><div class="adaptationDetailText adaptationDetailText2"><p class="av2"></p>av2</div></div></section></div><div class="clearfix"></div>';
 thtml += '</div>';
 thtml += '<footer><p class="center">(c)Recruit Career Co., Ltd.</footer>';
 tnum++;

 $('#printoutput').html(thtml);
 heigtSet();

 var tnum = 1;
 var t_colorNum = 0;
 var thtml = '';
 var t_out_html2 = '';

 var tMax = t_total_num;
 var tsize = (500/tMax);
 if (tsize>10){
  tsize = 10+2;
 }
 if (tsize<7){
  tsize = 7;
 }
 var tsieHtml = 'width:'+tsize+'px; height:'+tsize+'px;border-radius:'+tsize+'px;margin-top:'+tsize*(-0.5)+'px;margin-left:'+tsize*(-0.5)+'px';

 for(key in result){
  if(key!='group_name'){
   var group = result[key];
   t_colorNum++;
   var t_sub_group = group['name'];
   group['member'].forEach(function(member){
    if (member['adaptation_4']['standard_score']!=undefined && member['force']['standard_score']!=undefined){
     var t_adaptation_4=member['adaptation_4']['standard_score'];
     var t_force=member['force']['standard_score'];
     var tY = (1-(t_adaptation_4-20)/60)*$(".grphPlot").height();
     var tX = (t_force-20)/60*$(".grphPlot").width();
     var tGropeC ='groupColor'+t_colorNum;
     thtml += '<li class="'+tGropeC+'" style="top:'+tY+'px;left:'+tX+'px;'+tsieHtml+'"></li>';
    }else{
     console.log('no data!!!!')
    }
   });
  }
 }

 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(1) .meterBar').width((t_total_adaptation_1/(t_total_mid_num+t_total_nonmid_num)-20)/60*300+'%');
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(2) .meterBar').width((t_total_adaptation_2/(t_total_mid_num+t_total_nonmid_num)-20)/60*300+'%');
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(3) .meterBar').width((t_total_adaptation_3/t_total_num-20)/60*300+'%');
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(4) .meterBar').width((t_total_adaptation_4/t_total_num-20)/60*300+'%');
 if (t_total_mid_num==0 && t_total_nonmid_num==0){
  var t_display = 'none';
 }else{
  var t_display = 'block';
 }
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(1) .meterBar').css({'display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(2) .meterBar').css({'display':t_display});

 if (t_total_mid_num==0){
  var t_display = 'none';
 }else{
  var t_display = 'block';
 }
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(1) .av1').css({'left':(t_total_mid_adaptation_1/t_total_mid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(2) .av1').css({'left':(t_total_mid_adaptation_2/t_total_mid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(3) .av1').css({'left':(t_total_mid_adaptation_3/t_total_mid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(4) .av1').css({'left':(t_total_mid_adaptation_4/t_total_mid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});

 if (t_total_nonmid_num==0){
  var t_display = 'none';
 }else{
  var t_display = 'block';
 }
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(1) .av2').css({'left':(t_total_non_adaptation_1/t_total_nonmid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(2) .av2').css({'left':(t_total_non_adaptation_2/t_total_nonmid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(3) .av2').css({'left':(t_total_non_adaptation_3/t_total_nonmid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});
 $('.contentsPage'+tnum+' .adaptationCnt tr:nth-child(4) .av2').css({'left':(t_total_non_adaptation_4/t_total_nonmid_num-20)/60*300+'%','display':t_display});


 $('#output2').html(t_out_html2);


}
function heigtSet() {
 $('#printoutput>div').each(function(){
  console.log('test');
  console.log($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height());
  console.log($(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height());
  if ($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height()>$(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height()){
   $(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height($(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height()-15);
  }else{
   $(this).find('#adaptation .adaptationCnt').height($(this).find('#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt').height()+15);
  }
 });
}
```

```css
@charset "UTF-8";



#step,
#adaptation {
 background: #ECEFF1;
}
#adaptation h2 {
 background: #a1b2ba;
}

#adaptationDetail {
 background: #ECEFF1;
}
#adaptationDetail h2 {
 background: #a1b2ba;
}
#adaptationDetail table {
 background: none;
 margin-top: 5px;
}

/*#adaptationDetail thead {*/
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead {
 background: none;
 color: #a1b2ba;
 height: 40px;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) th{
 width: 40%;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) td{
 width: 20%;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th{
 border:none;
 height: 40px;
    padding: 0;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th:nth-child(3){
 letter-spacing: -0.05em;
    font-size: 90%;
}
 
 
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th.data p{
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: -0.5em;
 font-size: 110%;
 color: #333;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th.data p.titleUnder{
 text-align: center;
 margin-right:0;
 font-size: 130%;
}

#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th.dataTitleText:nth-child(1) p{
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: -1.5em;
 font-size: 110%;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th.dataTitleText:nth-child(3) p{
 text-align: center;
 font-size: 110%;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody.thead th.dataTitleText:nth-child(4) p{
 text-align: right;
 margin-right: -1em;
 font-size: 110%;
 color: #333;
 font-weight: bold;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr{
 background: #fff;
 border:1px solid #ECEFF1;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr th{
 padding: 20px 10px;
 font-size: 140%;
 height: 35px;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td{
 background: #CFD8DC;
 position: relative;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td:nth-child(3){
 background: #B0BEC5;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td:nth-child(4){
 background: #a1b2ba;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td:nth-child(5){
 background: #98abb4;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td p.meterBar{
 position: absolute;
 height:24px;
 left:0;
 top:50%;
 margin-top: -12px;
 width: 200px;
 display: block;
 background: #FDD835;
 z-index: 50;
}
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr:nth-child(4) td p.meterBar{
 background: #F9A825;
}
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText p.av2,
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText p.av1,
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td p.av2,
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td p.av1{
 position: absolute;
 top: 37.5px;
 left: 100px;
 width: 10px;
 height: 10px;
 -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
 -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
 transform: rotate(45deg);
 background: #009688;
 z-index: 60;
 margin-top: -5px;
 margin-left: -5px;
}
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText p.av2,
#adaptationDetail tbody:not(.thead) tr td p.av2{
 left: 120px;
 background: #9C27B0;
 z-index: 61;
}
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText{
 font-size: 85.7%;
 padding-left: 20px;
 margin-left: 10px;
 position: relative;
}
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText p.av2,
#adaptationDetail .adaptationDetailText p.av1{
 top: 6px;
    margin: 0;
    left: 5px;
}


#adaptationComment {
 /*margin-top: 10px;*/
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
#adaptationComment h2 {
    color: #78909C;
    padding: 8px 0;
}
#adaptationComment .hukidasi{
 background: #ECEFF1;
 line-height: 1.4em;
}
#adaptationComment .hukidasi:after {
 border-right-color: #ECEFF1;
}
#adaptation .adaptationCnt,
#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt{
 padding-top: 5px;
 /*height: 440px;*/
 /*height: 500px;*/
}
#adaptationDetail .adaptationCnt{
 padding: 20px 25px 10px;
 /*height: 425px;*/
 /*height: 485px;*/
}
footer {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>report</title>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="description" content="report" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Language" content="ja" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Style-Type" content="text/css" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Script-Type" content="text/javascript" />
<meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
<meta name="author" content="Action Switch & Advice" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1.0,minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0,user-scalable=no" />

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/reset.css" media="all">
<!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/style.css" media="all">-->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/sample.css" media="all">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/assets/css/sample.print.css" media="print">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
<script src="/assets/js/sample.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function Init()
{
  result=JSON.parse('<?php echo htmlspecialchars_decode($result); ?>');
  dataSet();
};

if( document.addEventListener )
{
 document.addEventListener( 'DOMContentLoaded', Init, false );
}

</script>

</head>
<body id="group">
 <section id="printoutput">
 </section>
<!--<hr />
  <div id="output" class="no-print"></div>
  <div id="output2" class="no-print"></div>
  <hr  class="no-print"/>
  <div  class="no-print" style="width:100%;"><?php echo $result; ?></div>-->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: can you share full code?

Comment: thank you for mention it.full code means full code of javascript? or any others?

Comment: Your HTML, CSS, and javascript. without structure, we can't able to the solution.

Comment: Ok.I added them.

Comment: If I use a `foreach` in my js code, `wkhtmltopdf` does not parse the javascript. It only parses 'simple' js like variable definition. Maybe this also refers to your error.